# JS: Обьединить элементы массива с одинаковым текстом в начале по группам

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив, где ряды элементов имеют одинаковый текст в начале, например:

```
var myArray = [
    "28|Какой то текст 1",
    "28|Какой то текст 2",
    "28|Какой то текст 3",
    "42|Какой то текст 4",
    "42|Какой то текст 5",
    "Фото1|Какой то текст 6",
    "Фото1|Какой то текст 7"
];
```

Нужно обьединить по группам (наверное через двухуровневые массивы?) все элементы которые начинаются на **28**, все которые начинаются на **42** и все которые начинаются на **Фото1** таким образом чтобы вывести их на странице в следующей форме:

```
28:
Какой то текст 1
Какой то текст 2
Какой то текст 3

42:
Какой то текст 4
Какой то текст 5

Фото1:
Какой то текст 6
Какой то текст 7
```

Текст в начале может быть и число, и собственно текст. Результат в конечном итоге нужно без всех запятых, квадратных и круглых скобок вывести в textarea, откуда он будет копироватся в буфер обмена, а потом вставлятся в обычный текстовый документ

Comment: что-нибудь пробовали сами? :)

Comment: судя по всему вам нужен не двухуровневый массив, а объект

Comment: Здравствуйте. Если в значениях массива присутствует разделитель (в Вашем примере символ "|"), то можно просто перебрать массив, деля значения на ключи и значения и на основе полученных данных сконструировать новый массив. Если Вы добавили разделитель в Вашем примере просто для наглядности, а в реальном использовании никакого разделителя не будет, то задача усложняется многократно.
`var newArr = [];
myArr.forEach(function(item, i){);`

Comment: Попробуйте, пожалуйста, сами решить задачу, а в случае возникновения затруднений, задавайте вопрос уже по ним. Сообщество не занимается написанием кода по заявкам.

Comment: Не занимайтесь вандализмом собственных вопросов. Хотите удалить - удаляйте (внизу под вопросом есть кнопка)

Comment: @KromStern наличие заплюсованного ответа отключает возможность удалить

Comment: @PashaPash как-же тогда быть автору вопроса, если он до сих пор продолжает отхватывать минусы?

Comment: @KromStern жизнь - боль.

Comment: @KromStern предлагаете удалить и забрать у отвечавших плюсы? думаю, им тоже будет обидно, причем обиднее чем автору вопроса (который получает минусы за то, что ничего не попытался сделать для решения).

Comment: @PashaPash Жизнь отвечающих тоже - боль. Наш разговор можно удалить. Спс.

Comment: Мой вопрос явно зацепил всех за живое. На этом сайте огромное количество подобных вопросов, где люди одним абзацом просят написать им код, их НИКТО не минусет и даже замечания не делает. Это явная дискриминация моего вопроса

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var myArray = [
  "28|Какой то текст 1",
  "28|Какой то текст 2",
  "28|Какой то текст 3",
  "42|Какой то текст 4",
  "42|Какой то текст 5",
  "Фото1|Какой то текст 6",
  "Фото1|Какой то текст 7"
];

document.getElementById('s').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 2);
var result = myArray.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  var parts = cur.split('|');
  if (!acc[parts[0]]) acc[parts[0]] = [];
  acc[parts[0]].push(parts[1]);
  return acc;
}, {});

document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = Object.keys(result).map(function(key){
  return  key+':\n'
        + result[key].join('\n');
  }).join('\n\n');
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
myArrr:
<pre id="s"></pre>
<textarea id="r"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если используется разделитель, то как-то так:

```js
var obj = {}, 
    arr = [
      "28|text 1",
      "28|text 2",
      "28|text 3",
      "42|text 4",
      "42|text 5",
      "Foto1|text 6",
      "Foto1|text 7"
    ];

// Обрабатываем каждый элемент массива
arr.forEach(function(item, i){
  
  // Делим строку по разделителю
  var keys = item.split("|");
  
  // Сохраняем ключ
  var key = keys[0];
  
  // Удаляем первый элемент массива
  keys.shift();
  
  // Если в объекте еще не существует массива с таким ключом, то создаем
  if(!obj[key]) {
    obj[key] = [];
  }
  
  // добавляем в объект остаток массива как строку
  obj[key].push(keys.join(""));
});

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
```

```html
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```